# How to open iOS system apps from HTML website?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

How could I put a link in html that would open an iOS system app such as settings or music from safari?

Something like:

```
<a href="settings">Open Settings App</a>
```

I have no idea what to search to find how to to this!

Comment: You need to know the app's custom URL scheme. There isn't one for the Settings app.

Comment: See [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Avoid the use of "solved" in your title.  If you've got an answer, you may answer your own question below.

Comment: @Makoto okay, I just did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the URL Scheme Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1